# Java, Reading a file that has UCS-2 Little Endian encodeing

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream, inputstreamreader

I'm trying to read a txt file that has the UCS-2 LE encoding, I have the following code below. the ??? is the encoding variable I need but I am not sure what it's supposed to be.

```
InputStream HostFile = new FileInputStream(Location + FileName);
Reader file = new InputStreamReader(HostFile, Charset.forName(???);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outLocation, "UTF-8");
```

Any ideas would be appreciated .

Comment: Try: `Charset.availableCharsets().forEach((t, u) -> {
            System.out.println(t + ": " + u);
        });` to see what available.

Comment: @Sedrick I figured it out is UTF-16LE thanks for the help

Comment: And it's in StandardCharsets constants.

Comment: UTF-16 is similar, but not identical to UCS-2. Meaning: this works or not depending on the characters used in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Reader file = new InputStreamReader(HostFile, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE");
```

Comment: Use `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE`